# How can I enter an image into mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not so sure how to process an image in PHP to put it into a blob type in MYSQLI. Here is my code so far...

```
<?php
    $servername = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question
    $username = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question
    $password = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question  
    $dbname = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect';
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!empty($_FILES['cf'] && $_POST['category']))
        {
            $file = $conn->real_escape_string($_FILES['cf']['tmp_name']);
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO adDatabase(".$category.") VALUES(".$file.")");
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Empty file';
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Now the value of the image is not null so the image is processed. But I cant seem to get it processed. Normally I make a variable $var = $_POST['cf']; then I add that into the query. I also tried $var = $_FILES['cf']; but it wont process. Is there something else I need to do to it to make it send/process properly?

**Edit based on answer**

I changed my PHP to something that resembles an answer

```
<?php
    $servername = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question
    $username = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question
    $password = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question  
    $dbname = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect';
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!empty($_FILES['cf'] && $_POST['category']))
        {
            try
            {
                $file = $conn->real_escape_string($_FILES['cf']['tmp_name']);
                $filecontents = File_Get_Contents($file);
                $filecontentssafe = $conn->real_escape_string($filecontents);
                mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO adDatabase(".$category.") VALUES(".$file.")");
                echo 'Query successful';
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo 'Could not perform action' + $e;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Empty file';
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Now I see Query successful, however.. nothing goes into the database.

**Edit - added retrieve file**

```
<?php
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $passcode = "";
    $dbname = "";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $passcode, $dbname);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect';
    }
    else 
    {
        try
        {
            $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `adDatabase`");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query))
            {
                $id = $row['ID'];
                $img = $row['img'];
                $image = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['food'] ).'" style="height: 12em; width: 12em; margin: 1em; padding: 0.9em; " >';
                echo $image;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
?>
```

How I retrieve information

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)`. what's in $_FILES is only information ABOUT the upload. it is NOT the actual file contents.

Comment: Neither SSL nor other security methods will help against SQL injection in any way.  You _need_ to understand vulnerabilities.  And, using parameters will fix your problem anyway.

Comment: I have learned something in CGI that can take care of that. But I have yet to install the correct software on the server. Anyway, I am just making the process in which it goes into the server. I am fixing vulrunabilities later.

Comment: I see no duplication. The referenced question pertains to empty values being added into a MYSQL database. This question refers to how to process an image and input it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you call mysql, $file only contains a path to the temporary uploaded file, not the data you want.

If you want MySQL to look at the file's path, and load its contents directly into your database, have a look at the MySQL function LOAD_FILE() here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Otherwise, if you'd like to do this in PHP, you'd want to pull the file's contents into a variable with something like

```
$file_contents=File_Get_Contents($file);
```

... and then use

```
$file_contents_safe=$conn->real_escape_string($file_contents);
```

before sticking $file_contents_safe into the database. Some people also like to Base64 encode.

Edit: Please also keep injection vulnerabilities in mind, as others have suggested. The name of the temporary file, and anything else coming in from post/apache shouldn't be trusted on its own.

Comment: I used base64 when retrieving images.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: I am trying it now

Comment: After putting it in a try catch, I see Query successful but nothing shows in the database. Let me edit my question so you can see what I changed.

Comment: Edited. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to stick with saving the blob content in the database, you could only save the file name in the database and do a regular file upload to a selected location. For that, you will need to add this before adding the content in the database

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["filename"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "YOUR_UPLOAD_DIR/{$name}");
```

And after uploading the file, you just need to store it's name in the database instead of storing the blob content. When displaying, you just need to access the actual file in your upload folder and show it. It's much cleaner solution, especially if you don't have to migrate files between servers.

The whole code would look something like this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['cf'] && $_POST['category']))
{
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["cf"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["cf"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "YOUR_UPLOAD_DIR/{$name}");
    $file = $conn->real_escape_string($name);
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO adDatabase(".$category.") VALUES(".$file.")");
}
```

Then when accessing it, you will need to pull the data from the database and just display it. If it is an image, it could be

```
<img src="<?php YOUR_UPLOAD_DIR.'/'.$name ?>"/>
```

**Otherwise:**

To insert the image data in your database do:

```
$content = file_get_contents($tmpName);
$file = $conn->real_escape_string($content);
$mime_type = mime_content_type($tmpName);
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO adDatabase(".$category.", mime_type) VALUES(".$file.", ".$mime_type.")");
```

Note I added a mimetype to the insert, because you will need it in order to be able to display the file properly later.

Then, when you want to display it, just pull the content from the db and echo it together with the proper header.

```
header('Content-type:'.$mime_type);
echo $content;
```

Comment: Unfortunely, I need the database. I usually use this method. But a db is necessary in this case..

Comment: Just updated the answer, should be more helpful now :)

Comment: Thank you, now what is mimi_content_type?

Comment: Mime, not mimi :) It's a php function that gets the mime type from a file. Check here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php. 
In case you're not familiar with it, the mime type describes the type of the file, which you need in order to be able to display it properly. If you only do an echo, without adding the content type with the proper mime type, you will only get a text that doesn't make any sense. Try commenting that line and you will be able to see the difference.

Comment: Okay let me go try. So I probably need to change the retrieve files too right?

Comment: Let me edit my question.

Comment: Ill show the retrieve file

Comment: Edited - will that method up there still work?

Comment: Works... it does not V_V

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115564/discussion-between-trajchevska-and-j-doe-doe-doe-doe).